# Implement `to_xstring()` to unite `to_string()` and `to_wstring()`

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, partial-specialization

Since the names of `to_string()` and `to_wstring()` differ, it's practically impossible to use them in generic functions. So, I'm planning to unite them with the following:

```
template <typename CharT, typename T>
auto to_xstring(const T& x);
```

The question is how to implement such a function template succinctly.

My current implementation is somewhat clumsy (with a `detail` namespace even). Since C++ does not allow partial specialization of function templates, I have the function template dispatch to structs that can be partial specialized. I'm looking for a better implementation.

```
namespace detail {

template <typename>
struct to_xstring_helper;

template <>
struct to_xstring_helper<char> {
  template <typename T>
  static std::string invoke(const T& x) {
    // explicitly pulls in `std` in case `T` is not a class type
    using std::to_string;
    return to_string(x);
  }
};

template <>
struct to_xstring_helper<wchar_t> {
  template <typename T>
  static std::wstring invoke(const T& x) {
    // explicitly pulls in `std` in case `T` is not a class type
    using std::to_wstring;
    return to_wstring(x);
  }
};

} // namespace detail

/// Calls either `to_string(x)` or `to_wstring(x)` based on `CharT`. Lookups in
/// namespace `std` and that of `T` (by ADL). Given a uniform name, this
/// function template facilitates writing generic functions.
template <typename CharT, typename T>
auto to_xstring(const T& x) {
  return detail::to_xstring_helper<CharT>::invoke(x);
}
```

Comment: The fact that "you can't have return type only difference in a function" is the reason that there is a `to_string` and `to_wstring` in the first place, so you can't avoid using some kind of struct/class as a helper.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: Because `to_string` and `to_wstring` are declared as `template<typename T> std::string& to_string` and `template<typename T> std::wstring& to_wstring`, so you still need some way to produce one function that returns a different type based on the return value. But it may work a little better to do `std::basic_string<CharT> tmp; my_to_xstring(tmp, x); return tmp;` [this relies on knowing how `std::wstring` or `std::string` are declared via `std::basic_string`, but I think that is part of the standard.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I don't think so. The functions differ not only in the return type but also in the template argument `CharT`.

Comment: Right, I meant for the actual `to_xstring` implementation itself - you need a function that can be ditinguished by the compiler, and you can't have two functions that are ONLY different in terms of return value.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I just realized that parameter overloading doesn't apply. I deleted my comment before you posted the reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) for this, no? E.g., using [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if):

```
template <typename CharT, typename T>                                                                                                                                                                    
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<CharT, char>::value, std::string>::type 
    to_xstring(const T &t)
{
    return std::to_string(t);
}


template <typename CharT, typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<CharT, char>::value, std::wstring>::type 
    to_xstring(const T &t)
{
    return std::to_wstring(t);
}
```

Comment: Like I have always been forgetting this SFINAE thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use static dispatch without a template struct and partial specialization, for instance like this:

```
namespace detail {

  template<typename T>
  std::string to_string_helper_impl(const T& x, char) {
    using std::to_string;
    return to_string(x);
  }

  template <typename T>
  static std::wstring to_string_helper_impl(const T& x, wchar_t) {
    using std::to_wstring;
    return to_wstring(x);
  }

}

template <typename CharT, typename T>
auto to_xstring(const T& x) {
  return detail::to_string_helper_impl(x, CharT{});
}
```